# CSS pop up menu to overflow/overlap in JQuery layout panes

Tags: css, popup, jquery-layout

I' using the JQuery layout and define only the north, west and center panes. On the left side (west pane) I'm building a CSS pop up menu. With the abundance of CSS pop up menus around the web, I have no trouble making it to work. The problem that I'm facing is that the pop up menu does not overlap the center pane. You can see this behavior in [my JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/A3g8s/). I have tried setting `overflow: visible; z-index: 10001;`but it didn't solve anything. What can I try next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add this styles

```
.ui-layout-west{
   z-index: 50;
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Update

```
.ui-layout-west{
   z-index: 50 !important;
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: The other answer is better.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution came after consulting the docs with a higher degree of attention (i.e. higher than before...). The API provides a method for setting the overflow on a particular pane. In may case, the "west" pane needed to overflow it's content. The following code did the trick:

```
mylayout.allowOverflow("west");
```

*Edit*: I'm not going to mark my answer as accepted. Kison's answer provided a working solution at the time and should be credited.